# Redux receiving props delay after dispatch calling from componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

State is not updated immediately after receiving data

**Accounts.js** like this

```js
class Accounts extends Component {

  componentDidMount()
  {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchAccountsAction())
  }
  render(){
    const accInfo = this.props.accounts // Not getting data immediately 
    return (
      <Details accInfo = {accInfo} />
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  console.log('state',state);
  return {
    accounts:state.accounts
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Accounts)
```

**Action.js** like this

```js
const fetchAccountsAction = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const res = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'Application/json',
        'Authorization': token,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });

    const data = await res.json()
    if (data) {
      dispatch(fetchAccounts(data))
    }
  }
}

export function fetchAccounts(accounts)
{
    console.log('accounts',accounts) // Am getting data here
    return {
        type: FETCH_ACCOUNTS,
        accounts : accounts
    }
}
```

**Reducer.js** like this

```
const initialState = {
    accounts : [],
    error:null
}

export function accountsReducer(state=initialState,action) {

    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_ACCOUNTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                accounts:action.accounts
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

When `componentDidMount` happened props not receiving immediately because there is a delay in API response. Could you please help with the props access after receiving the data from API.

Thank you.

Comment: Fetching from an api naturally takes time, try adding a loader for your component until the data is fetched from the api.

Comment: `const accInfo = this.props.accounts ` still not accessible after data receives. How to access state data after response came.

Comment: It seem you don't write your data into redux store. Can you describe when you write data from response?

Comment: Props should be updated when the redux state is updated if everything is set up properly. Double check your reducer.

Comment: I have updated `reducer ` code. Is there any wrong with my `reducer` js file

Comment: My `<Details accInfo = {accInfo} />` component not receiving the data even after receiving the response.

Comment: Can you describe how did you create redux store? Did you use combine reducers?

Answer (score 0):

What happens here:

1. `cDM` is called, action is dispatched.
2. If action creator was sync(just a plain action + straight reducer without any async operations) state would be updated
3. `render()` happens with previous props(old state)
4. redux's `store.subscribe()` makes wrapper(created by `connect`) to recalculate all that `mapStateToProps`/`mapDispatchToProps`
5. since step #3 returned different values wrapper re-renders your component with new `props`
6. `render()` happens with new props

That fact your action creator is async by its nature switch #2 and #3 with their places. But anyway, your first render will be with old store values.

So you better handle that accordingly(like checking if some object is not `undefined` anymore or use brand new [optional chaining](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining) to get safe from "cannot read property ... of null")